# Laravel UpdateOrCreate with if condition

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I'm using laravel 9 and would like to make a `updateOrCreate` query with a condition tied to it.

I want to toggle between two statuses inside the UpdateOrCreate condition.

I know you can use conditionally if statements in stuff like `OrderByRaw` as demonstrated below:

```
->orderByRaw("IF(id = {$this->request['filterID']}, 0,1)");
```

I tried something similar for the `updateOrCreate` like below:

```
Auth::user()->favorites()->updateOrCreate([
    'favoriteable_id' => 2,
    'favoriteable_type' => Asset::class,
],[
    "status" => "IF(status = {$active}, {$inactive},{$active})"
]);
```

I have a table where the status defaults to status `active`; that's fine when creating the record. However, when the user toggles the favorite functionality, I would like the record to switch between `active` and `inactive` status.

Is there any way to do this with the inbuild query builder from eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may rewrite the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany@updateOrCreate` method to look like this:

```
tap(Auth::user()->favorites()->firstOrNew([
    'favoriteable_id' => 2,
    'favoriteable_type' => Asset::class,
]), function ($instance) {
        $instance->fill(['status' => $instance->status == 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active']);

        $instance->save();
})
```

Comment: That's actually pretty cool, didn't know about the Tap helper function, thank you :)